# show div on checkbox select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<div class='row homes center'>
  <div class='span1'></div>

  <div class='row homes center'>
    <div class='span1'></div>

    <div class='hometype span2'>
      <div class='checked'></div>

      <label for='prairie'>
        <img src='img/prairie.png' >
      </label>

      <input id='prairie' name='hometypes' type='checkbox' value='Prairie'>
    </div>

    <div class='hometype span2'>
      <div class='checked'></div>

      <label for='traditional'>
        <img src='img/traditional.png'>
      </label>

      <input id='traditional' name='hometypes' type='checkbox' value='Traditional'>
    </div>

    <div class='hometype span2'>
      <div class='checked'></div>

      <label for='transitional'>
        <img src='img/transitional.png'>
      </label>

      <input id='transitional' name='hometypes' type='checkbox' value='Transitional'>
    </div>

    <div class='hometype span2'>
      <div class='checked'></div>

      <label for='bungalow'>
        <img src='img/bungalow.png'>
      </label>

      <input id='bungalow' name='hometypes' type='checkbox' value="Bungalow">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='fixed_button homes hidden'>
    <a class='button blue_button continue continue_type'>Continue &rarr;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.choose_style input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
  if ($('input[name=homestyles]:checked').val()) {
    $('.homes').removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

I need the button to display once any of the checkboxes are checked. Nothing happens when checkbox is clicked though. What am I doing wrong? I need to remove the `.hidden` from the button.

Comment: Not sure if this is it, or just a copy-paste error, but your Jquery is checking for elements with the name `homestyles` however, your HTML markup shows every name to be `hometypes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.is(':checked')` returns  true if any of the elements in the collection are checked :

```
$('.choose_style input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
    if ( $('input[name=homestyles]').is(':checked') ) {           
        $('.homes').removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

note that the posted markup has no `.choose_style` or `homestyles` elements ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.hometype  input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function (){
    if ($('input[name="hometypes"]').is(':checked')) {           
        $('.fixed_button.homes').removeClass('hidden');
    }
    else{
        $('.fixed_button.homes').addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2zH4p/)

Answer (score 0):

You have so many mistakes in your code. I fixed few of them to make it work http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/jNU4B/

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
    if ($('input[name=homestyles]:checked')) {
        $('.homes').removeClass('hidden');
    }
 });
```